# Access denied on setting property after clearing same property

Tags: c++, windows, com, windows-10

I have been trying to edit the metadata of some audio files using Windows' `IPropertyStore` methods, and came across this strange problem. After setting an empty `PROPVARIANT` value to a property store's key via `IPropertyStore::SetValue()`, following attempts to set that key's value fail with a return value of `0x80030005`, which Visual Studio informs me is `Access Denied.`.
This is the smallest example with which I could produce this behaviour:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <PropIdl.h>
#include <Propsys.h>
#include <propkey.h>
#include <propvarutil.h>
#include <ShObjIdl.h>
#include <Windows.h>


namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main() {
    HRESULT hr;

    if (FAILED(hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED))) {
        // Handle error...
    }

    fs::path const test_path(fs::current_path() / "test.mp3");

    CComPtr<IPropertyStore> property_store;
    if (FAILED(hr = SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(test_path.wstring().c_str(), NULL, GPS_READWRITE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&property_store)))) {
        // Handle error...
    }

    // Set an empty value to the key
    {
        PROPVARIANT property{};
        PropVariantInit(&property);

        if (FAILED(hr = property_store->SetValue(PKEY_Title, property))) {
            // Handle error...
        }

        if (FAILED(hr = PropVariantClear(&property))) {
            // Handle error...
        }
    }

    // Write a new value to the same key
    {
        PROPVARIANT property{};
        if (FAILED(hr = InitPropVariantFromString(L"test file", &property))) {
            // Handle error...
        }

        if (FAILED(hr = property_store->SetValue(PKEY_Title, property))) {
            // Always fails here with hr == 0x80030005 "Access Denied."
        }

        if (FAILED(hr = PropVariantClear(&property))) {
            // Handle error...
        }
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = property_store->Commit())) {
        // Handle error...
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

This only seems to occur when setting an empty value first; any other value results in the program running as expected, with both changes written successfully.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, it *is* fine to write an empty value to a key - I can successfully write the empty value by itself and the changes are reflected when I view the file's properties in Explorer.
Furthermore, I don't understand how the error could possibly be "access denied" - the user the program is running under (my standard account) definitely has permissions to change the key (I can go into Properties in Explorer and manually change the key's value just fine), and how could it possibly be access denied for only *one* of the two key accesses?

**So why can't I write an empty value to a key and then overwrite it later?**

<sub>For those wondering why I need to clear a key and then immediately write a new value to it - I don't actually. That sequence of events just happens to occur in a larger program where all the properties are cleared and then later on certain keys are re-populated.</sub>

**Update:**
I've since experimented more with how the `IPropertyStore` object handles file access.
When the `IPropertyStore` object is initialised with a file (in this case through `SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName()`), it seems to open the file exclusively - as if through calling `CreateFile()` with `0` as the sharing mode. Once opened, none of my various attempts to open the file again via `CreateFile()` succeeded; all failed with `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`. I believe this rules out another process (or even my program's process) from "stealing" the file access rights after the first property change (even though, as I discussed in the comments, property changes are not written until `IPropertyStore::Commit()` is called).

Even once the `IPropertyStore::Commit()` method is called, which writes all pending property changes to the file, the file remains open, exclusively. Reopening the file at this point is still not possible as far as I observed. This is peculiar, since the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761470(v=vs.85).aspx) states "[b]efore it returns, Commit releases the file stream or path with which the handler was initialized". What I found was until the `IPropertyStore` object was released (`IUnknown::Release()`), the associated file remained opened.

Committing and releasing the `IPropertyStore` object after clearing the key, then recreating it and writing the new value, seems to work perfectly. The key is successfully cleared, and then successfully rewritten. However this still leaves the original question open: why *can't* I do the clear and rewrite in one open/write/commit cycle of the property store?

Comment: Setting the value to VT_EMPTY is semantically identical to deleting the key, as GetValue returns empty when the property does not exist https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761473.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier I know, that's what I want to do. But then [SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761475(v=vs.85).aspx) should re-add the property if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Changing the property gives a pretty good reason for *another* process to re-open the file.  Could be Explorer, could be a shell extension, the installed anti-malware product is always a good candidate.  Expectation is that you have to spin your wheels for a bit to try again later.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't have any 3rd party anti-malware, just got the inbuilt Windows Defender thing. Turned that off and tried and no luck... Resource Monitor shows my program is the only with a handle on the test file (not sure if that's a useful indicator though).

Comment: @HansPassant also note that the changes aren't written to the file until IPropertyStore::Commit() is called, which never gets executed. Additionally, as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761470(v=vs.85).aspx), the file is not released until said function is executed, so it's not as though another process could "steal" the file in between SetValue() calls.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the property to VT_EMPTY, you don't "set" its value, you don't "write an empty value", you don't "clear" it, you *remove* it. Note that the running property store's count is decremented (`GetCount`), and you can't use `GetAt` either anymore.

Official documentation for [IPropertyStore::SetValue method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761475.aspx) is very clear:

> Removing a property values from a
>   property store is not supported and could lead to unexpected results.

Comment: If removing the property value is not allowed like I was trying, then I'd very much like to know how it *is* allowed. Because unless I'm very mistaken, clearing the value via Properties in Explorer does remove the key.

Comment: What they probably mean is it does not work as one could expect. Once it's been removed, you must commit, release the store, and recreate another store to be able to use that property again.

Comment: Hmm... quite possibly. And for the time being I think I'll have to work around it like that. Would be really handy if they had mentioned all this stuff in the documentation though.