# Changing the metadata like title, author using IMFSinkWriter

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-media-foundation

I'm using the SinkWriter example from [Tutorial: Using the Sink Writer to Encode Video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--using-the-sink-writer-to-encode-video). I would like to add a title to the mp4 file generated similar to the following.

```
_bstr_t strTitle =L"dksldk";

CComPtr<IWMHeaderInfo> pHeaderInfo;
ComCheck(m_pWriter->QueryInterface( IID_IWMHeaderInfo, (void**)&pHeaderInfo ));
ComCheck(pHeaderInfo->SetAttribute( 0,  g_wszWMTitle, 
WMT_TYPE_STRING, (BYTE*)(wchar_t *)strTitle, 2*(strTitle.length()+1)));
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

[Sink Writer API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/sink-writer) does not offer the requested capability. However you can complete writing MP4 file, close sink writer instance and then use Media Foundation MPEG-4 Property Handler (see [`SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shgetpropertystorefromparsingname) and code snippet here: [Access denied on setting property after clearing same property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049031/access-denied-on-setting-property-after-clearing-same-property)) to add properties to finished file.